# Checking if type is streamable fails in a weird way

Tags: c++, c++17

I have a weird issue in that my code works perfectly when I have it all in one file, but separating it to libraries causes some weird issues. Here's how it's supposed to work:

```
#include <iostream>

struct streamable_thing
{
    int a;
    int b;
};

struct nonstreamable_thing
{
    int a;
    int b;
};


std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& p_os, const streamable_thing & p_data);
std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& p_is, streamable_thing & p_data);

template <typename S, typename T, class = void>
struct is_stream_writeable : std::false_type{};

template <typename S, typename T>
struct is_stream_writeable<S,T, std::void_t<decltype(std::declval<S&>() << std::declval<const T &>())>> : std::true_type{};

template <typename S, typename T, typename std::enable_if<!is_stream_writeable<S,T>::value>::type* = nullptr>
static bool write_if_ok(S & p_stream, T const& p_value)
{
  p_stream << "No stream operator for [" << typeid(T).name() << "]\n";
  return false;
}
template <typename S, typename T, typename std::enable_if<is_stream_writeable<S, T>::value>::type * = nullptr>
static bool write_if_ok(S & p_stream, T const& p_value)
{
  p_stream << p_value << "\n";
  return true;
}

int main()
{
    write_if_ok(std::cout, streamable_thing{1,2});
    write_if_ok(std::cout, nonstreamable_thing{1,2});
}

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& p_os, const streamable_thing & p_data)
{
  p_os << '[' << p_data.a << ", " << p_data.b << ']';
  return p_os;
}

std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& p_is, streamable_thing & p_data)
{

  return p_is;
}
```

This works as expected, it prints out:

```
[1, 2]
No stream operator for [19nonstreamable_thing]
```

When I split this into a couple files and two separate libraries and try to use it like this:

```
glm::vec3 glmvec{1,2,3}; // I added stream functions for glm::vec3, I made the structs in the example to make it portable.
std::cout << glmvec; // This works
write_if_ok(std::cout, glmvec); // This doesn't
```

What to me sounds very odd is the error message:

```
error: no match for 'operator<<' (operand types are 'std::basic_ostream<char>' and 'const glm::vec<3, float, glm::packed_highp>')
```

I'm very confused about why this error happens, I mean I guess it's correct when it uses the version where stream operations for the type exist. But how does it end up not having them then? Does it do this in some weird passes, where first it thinks it has it, but then it doesn't?

And on top of that, why does it work when I just use std::cout directly, shouldn't that cause a compilation error if there truly isn't support for it?

Is there any way for me to build an example in some online compiler where I could create libraries? I couldn't replicate this issue when it's all in a single file.

---

Here's another attempt to replicate the issue, I added the namespaces which should cause issues but don't? Maybe I misunderstood something.
https://www.online-cpp.com/2dKGAYjk45

Comment: My spidey senses say you overloaded `operator<<` for `glm::vec3` in the wrong namespace. It must be in the same namespace as one of the operands (supposedly `namespace glm`, as `std` is off limits), where [ADL](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/adl) can find. Otherwise it will appear to work on the surface, but then get shadowed easily when called from inside a namespace that contains any unrelated `operator<<`.

Comment: If I didn't guess correctly, please make a [mcve].

Comment: There is also possible conflict of operators in Koenig lookup if said operators were overloaded too late

Comment: @HolyBlackCat How does that explanation fit the fact that the line where I use std::cout directly works?

Comment: Can't say for sure without a [mcve]. The explanation in my first comment requires there to be several namespaces for this issue to occur, but your example isn't showing any. Either there's some other scenario where this breaks that I don't know about, or the example is bad.

Comment: It took a while to compile the big project this is used in, and it fixed the issue. I'm just very confused as to why the std::cout one worked. I'd like to understand, but I guess it goes too deep into cosmic horror.

Comment: @Swift-FridayPie overloaded too late? what does that mean?

Comment: @0xbaadf00d Does `write_if_ok` actually reside in the global scope, or is it in a namespace? Perhaps `using`[`namespace`] brings it into the scope?

Comment: Templates are only ever generated for argument types that are known to be in use. 
Was your template (complete with the functions it intends to use) header-only in the split library, or is it possible that the compiler didn't generate the binaries for the type you'd like to use, and then your other library couldn't find them?

Comment: cvref qulification of the type might be the cause. Is there a reason why instead of `concept`s you are sticking with **traits**? `template<typename dst, typename src> concept left_shiftable = requires (dst & left, src right){{left<<right}->std::same_as<dst &>;};`

Comment: meaning it wasn't available immediately where ADL could find. You can define them after template definition but before instantiation, albeit they MUST be in same namespace as argument types. After instantiation (which accidently may happen if you have a virtual member function) is "too late". Badly planned code indeed may become a cosmic horror sucking away the sanity.

Comment: @Red.Wave I'm using 17, isn't that part of 20?

Comment: @Swift-FridayPie I don't get how my example doesn't fail if I move the structs to a namespace and then refer to them by namespace::streamable_thing, while keeping the operators in global scope.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Yeah, there are quite a few namespaces in the real thing, I left them out of the example because I didn't think they could cause issues, while they do. I tried adding a number of namespaces to my example but I just can't get it to NOT work. I'm content now that it works, even though I didn't fully understand why it didn't fail in my example code(even with a number of namespaces).

Comment: You need to call `<<` from another namespace, and that namespace has to contain its own `operator<<` for some unrelated parameter types. That will then shadow `operator<<(..., glm::vec3)` in the global scope.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Ok, that sounds like a good explanation, I'll try if I can replicate it.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat No matter what namespaces I throw at it, I just can't get it to break the same way https://www.online-cpp.com/tb0RymHnhq the test4 namespace broke the stream operations, but the template broke too, which is the issue. I need the stream operations to not work, but the trait to think that it does so that it ends up trying to use the stream operation and then fail the compilation when it doesn't exist. Maybe I'm just not smart enough to understand this stuff.

Comment: Again, you need another unrelated `operator<<` in the namespace that calls `<<`. In your case, in `namespace test2`.

Comment: Yeah, I can get it to break the stream operator for streamable_thing by adding the unrelated operator. But it breaks it so that the trait notices it too. I guess it's fine now that it works. If you have the time, can you modify my example so that it causes a compiler error? It's fine if you don't.

Comment: I guess recommending to upgrade to C++20 is not the list of options.

Comment: Yeah, not in my hands.